# Kivy screenmanager current screen not switching (at least not visually). Using kivymd

Tags: python, windows, kivy

I am working on a login system with python, kivymd, and kivy's screenmanager to switch, however, when I try to switch the screen from the login screen to another one nothing happens, no errors, and no visual changes. This is a reproducible example:

.py file

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp

class Screen1(Screen):
    def SwitchScreen(self):
        scrMng.current = "screen2"

class Screen2(Screen):
    def SwitchScreen(self):
        scrMng.current = "screen1"

scrMng = ScreenManager()
scrMng.add_widget(Screen1(name = "screen1"))
scrMng.add_widget(Screen2(name = "screen2"))

class TestApp(MDApp):
        def build(self):
            return Builder.load_file("main.kv")


TestApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
ScreenManager:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:

<Screen1>
    name: "screen1"
    
    MDCard:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 300, 350
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        elevation: 10
        padding: 25
        spacing: 25
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDLabel:
            text: "Screen2"
            font_size: 40
            halign: "center"
            font_bold: True
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: (0.20, 0.33, 1.00, 1)

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "SWITCH"
            font_size: 12
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            on_press: self.parent.parent.SwitchScreen()

<Screen2>
    name: "screen2"
    
    MDCard:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 300, 350
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        elevation: 10
        padding: 25
        spacing: 25
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDLabel:
            text: "Screen1"
            font_size: 40
            halign: "center"
            font_bold: True
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: (0.20, 0.33, 1.00, 1)

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: "SWITCH"
            font_size: 12
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
            on_press: self.parent.parent.SwitchScreen()
```

Python version: 3.9.9
Kivy version: 2.0.0

Any help is appreaciated!

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson I just edited the post adding an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a GUI using the lines:

```
scrMng = ScreenManager()
scrMng.add_widget(Screen1(name = "screen1"))
scrMng.add_widget(Screen2(name = "screen2"))
```

But the `scrMng` created above is never used, so those lines can be eliminated. And the reference to `scrMng` in the python code will do nothing, since `scrMng` is not actually part of your app.

Your GUI is actually created by the line:

```
return Builder.load_file("main.kv")
```

Then the `Screen` classes can become:

```
class Screen1(Screen):
    def SwitchScreen(self):
        self.manager.current = "screen2"

class Screen2(Screen):
    def SwitchScreen(self):
        self.manager.current = "screen1"
```

Note that `self.manager` in a `Screen` class is always a reference to its `ScreenManager`.